# Microsoft ODBC driver conflict with libodbc.so.2 installing php-ldap

Tags: php, odbc, unixodbc

I have the Microsoft ODBC driver installed under Centos working fine with UnixODBC 2.3.0 as instructed. I am trying to install php-ldap and it will upgrade my php which is fine, except it fails on a dependency which is:

libodbc.so.2()(64bit) is needed by php-odbc-5.4.18-1.el6.remi.x86_64

I remember having trouble with this file which I had to hotlink to libodbc.so.1 to get php-pdo working. Now for the upgrade in PHP it's looking for that file and I guess maybe I have the 32 bit installed instead of the 64 bit. I tried copying over the 2.3.1 version and using the standard 2.2.4 but nothing seems to work.

It lives in

```
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2
```

I feel like if I get the wrong driver in there, PHP-PDO/MS ODBC will stop working just so php-ldap can work. My current PHP version is 5.4.16 and I'd rather just get the php-ldap for that but all the links seem dead - I just want to install it via RPM. Right now I'm using the remi repo to get the latest PHP version and would like an upgrade path without the libodbc causing issues.

ldd on the file:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff25fce000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5754ac9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f57548ac000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5754518000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5754f41000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was manually install php_pdo by forcing the RPM's. It worked so I don't know what the issue really is...  it's a difficult installation to perform with microsoft drivers && linux.

Comment: Have similar issue while installing the odbc driver 13 for MSSQL server.
`error: Failed dependencies:
        libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit) is needed by msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64
        unixODBC >= 2.3.1 is needed by msodbcsql-13.1.4.0-1.x86_64
`
Could you please help me out on what you exactly did?

Comment: Disabled priorities by editing `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf` and set `enabled = 0` and was able to resolve the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` the path to your driver needs  to change
For Example (FreeTDS)

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS v0.91
Driver=/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
...
```

Comment: What I did was manually install php_pdo by forcing the RPM's. It worked so I don't know what the issue really is...  it's a difficult installation to perform.

Comment: Btw the path was correct and everything, I think it was more to do with installation process and some little error somewhere...